# Three in a lock

Tags: lateral-thinking, number-sequence, story, sports

In the 1980s, a German spy was assigned a mission to retrieve a set of important documents kept inside a British outpost. The spy knew that the documents were locked in a safe, which the password was a three-integer-sequence. He had to make sure the password was correct, as the safe was connected to an alarm that would be triggered whenever any unauthorized access was detected.

The German intelligence agency acquired several number sequences from a British traitor. The traitor insisted that these sequences contained vital information about the password. However, he could not figure out what the actual password was; he just knew that `A`, `B`, `C` were the three integers needed to be keyed in, and they were somehow related to a kind of sports.

The number sequences were:

**Seq.1** - 14, 32, 16, `A`, 28, 18, 24
**Seq.2** - 19, 3, `B`, 2, 15, 10, 6
**Seq.3** - 3, 54, `C`, 39, 18, 30, 45

Do you know what `A`, `B`, `C` are?

---

*Hint*

> The numbers in **Seq.2** can be seen in that sport **directly**, while those in the other two sequences are not that obvious.

---

**Visual Explanation to the answer**

> [image: Sequences on a dartboard]
>
>  **Seq.1** - Blue, clockwise. They are the **doubles**.
>  **Seq.2** - Orange, counter-clockwise. They are the **singles**.
>  **Seq.3** - Purple, clockwise. They are the **trebles** or **triples**.

Comment: "Do you know what A, B, C are?" They are numbers.

Comment: @Therandomguy Yes, you got it! And, what numbers are they?

Comment: 'Working about it

Comment: The second sequence makes me thing about a lacrosse field... Only the 19 is the odd one and there isn't a clear indication on what should fill in the blank.

Comment: @Martijn I am not sure if this hint is useful: `In what kind of sports can these numbers be seen very often?`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These sequences are found on a

> dartboard 
>  Seq1 and Seq3 clockwise and Seq2 counter-clockwise.

> Seq1: 7, 16, 8, 11, 14, 9 12   all multiplied with 2: A => 22 
>  Seq2: 19, 3, 17, 2, 15, 10, 6:  B => 17 
>  Seq3: 1, 18, 4, 13, 6, 10, 15  all multiplied with 3: C => 12

Thanks to Bungicasse for the questions, which helped me a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry I can't comment because I don't have high enough reputation. Is it the whole line of numbers that are seen often or is it the three numbers that is often seen together?

Is it for instance 14, 32, 16, A, 28, 18, 24 that is often seen in a sport or is it A, B, C?

**Edit:**

**Spoiler:** Seq. 2 is:

> A dartboard - 19,3,**17**,2,15,10,6. Damn didn't realise that the rest was also from a dartboard untill it was alrady guessed :(

Comment: I have added a hint to answer your question. =)

Comment: I was wondering why you didn't answer the question. =)

Comment: I didn't realise untill Wa Kai had already guessed it xD